# Compositeness test for specific class of $N=k \cdot b^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Can you give a counterexample to the conjecture given below ?

*Def 1.*

Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}\right)$ .

*Def 2.*

Let $N=k \cdot b^n-1$ such that $k>0$ , $3 \not\mid k$ , $b>0$ , $b$ is even number, $3 \not\mid b$  and $n > 2$ .

*Def 3.*

Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=P_{kb/2}(P_{b/2}(4))$

---

***Conjecture***

> If $N$ is prime then $S_{n-2} \equiv 0\pmod{N}$.

---

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdjLEOwiAURfcm_QfSCZAGIdEF3-hoP8GktJiStkAANf69NMZBp_fuyb2HU3R22UTk7qs2MaGZadS7ETlEeV3NcBRKg1QODqquEkga_DJMRr_SZB54pppLJtgP_CBJSFl0UCpX14ryDznCdp-TXQwu6QSulSzBxY_4T6yLIXFJWEdUae5AbDZ7wwlgz0K0LuMmRK97vRhU8moa8uWDX4NPNhe0rd5KHESN&lang=gp) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.

Let us prove by induction that
$$S_i=p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}$$
where $p=2-\sqrt 3,q=2+\sqrt 3$ with $pq=1$.
$$\small\begin{align}S_0&=P_{kb/2}(P_{b/2}(4))\\\\&=P_{kb/2}\left(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}\right)\\\\&=2^{-kb/2}\left(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}-\sqrt{(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})^2-4}\right)^{kb/2}+2^{-kb/2}\left(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}+\sqrt{(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})^2-4}\right)^{kb/2}\\\\&=2^{-kb/2}\left(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}-\left(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2}\right)\right)^{kb/2}+2^{-kb/2}\left(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}+\left(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2}\right)\right)^{kb/2}\\\\&=p^{kb^2/4}+q^{kb^2/4}\end{align}$$

Supposing that $S_i=p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}$ gives that
$$\small\begin{align}S_{i+1}&=P_b(S_i)\\\\&=P_b(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4})\\\\&=2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-\sqrt{(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4})^2-4}\right)^{b}\\\\&\qquad+2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}+\sqrt{(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4})^2-4}\right)^{b}\\\\&=2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-\left(q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-p^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)\right)^{b}\\\\&\qquad+2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}+\left(q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-p^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)\right)^{b}\\\\&=p^{kb^{i+3}/4}+q^{kb^{i+3}/4}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Now
$$S_{n-2}=p^{(N+1)/4}+q^{(N+1)/4}$$
Squaring the both sides gives
$$S_{n-2}^2=p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2}+2\tag1$$
Using that
$$\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt 3}=\frac{\sqrt 3\pm 1}{\sqrt 2}$$
we get
$$\begin{align}2^{(N+1)/2}(p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2})&=(\sqrt 3-1)^{N+1}+(\sqrt 3+1)^{N+1}\\\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{i}(\sqrt 3)^{i}((-1)^{N+1-i}+1^{N+1-i})\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(N+1)/2}\binom{N+1}{2j}(\sqrt 3)^{2j}\cdot 2\\\\&\equiv 2+2\cdot 3^{(N+1)/2}\qquad\pmod N\\\\&\equiv 2+2\cdot (-3)\qquad\pmod N\\\\&\equiv -4\qquad\pmod N\end{align}$$
where 
$$3^{(N+1)/2}=3\cdot 3^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 3\left(\frac 3N\right)=3\cdot\frac{(-1)^{\frac{3-1}{2}\cdot\frac{N-1}{2}}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=3\cdot\frac{-1}{1}=-3\pmod N$$
Since $$2^{(N+1)/2}=2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 2\left(\frac 2N\right)=2\cdot (-1)^{(N^2-1)/8}\equiv 2\pmod N$$ is coprime to $N$, we get
$$p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2}\equiv -2\pmod N\tag2$$
It follows from $(1)(2)$ that
$$S_{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod N$$
as conjectured.